# Smooth scrolling issue using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm learning JavaScript, so I decided to create a one page website along the process. I want to implement smooth scrolling in the page, but it doesn't work even though the code appears clean and correct. I need help figuring out the issue.

Basically what's happening is when I click a link in the navigation bar to take me down the target page, it doesn't scroll at all or even do anything. And also, when I try to  scroll it normally after I click a link, the scrolling shakes and doesn't let me keep scrolling.

I already checked the debugger for error, and there is no errors according to the debugger(at least no syntax errors).

How can I find the issue and how to solve it?

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var targetDistance = 0;
var distanceScrolled = 0;
var bodyHeight = 0;
var Ydistance = 0;
var marginY = 0;
var speed = 55;
var tempDist = 24;


function smoothScroll(el) {
targetDistance = document.getElementsByClassName(el).offsetTop;    //Target distance to scroll from current element
distanceScrolled = window.pageYOffset;                             //Distance scrolled from current element to target element
bodyHeight = document.body.offsetHeight;                           //Maximum distance of the body to scroll from the current element
Ydistance = distanceScrolled + window.innerHeight;                 //Total distance scrolled from the current element to the bottom

var setScroll = setTimeout(function(){
    smoothScroll(el);
}, 1);


//Stop Scrolling when it hits bottom of the page
if (Ydistance >=bodyHeight) {
     clearTimeout(setScroll);
}

//Scroll if the distance scrolled is less than the target distance
 else if(distanceScrolled < targetDistance - 24) {
    var distToScroll = distanceScrolled + 24;
     window.scroll(0, distToScroll);

}

//stop when the distance scrolled equals or is greater than the target distance
else {
window.scroll(0, distToScroll);
}
}
```

if you Guys need the HTML5 code, here it is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"> 
 <head>
    <title>Smooth Scrolling</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>

 <body>

    <div id="allPages" class="Page1">
        <div class="navBar">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="smoothScroll('Page4'); return false;">Contacts</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" onclick="smoothScroll('Page3'); return false;">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="smoothScroll('Page2'); return false;">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="smoothScroll('Page1'); return false;">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

     <div id="allPages" class="Page2">

    </div>

     <div id="allPages" class="Page3">

    </div>

     <div id="allPages" class="Page4">

    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
```

In case you also need the CSS code, here it is:

```
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 18px;
}



.body {
 height: 100%; 
}

.navBar {
margin-top: 2%;
}
.Page1 {
 height: 100vh; 
}

.Page1 ul {
list-style: none;
margin-right: 10%;
margin-left: 65%;
}

.Page1 ul a {
float: right; 
text-decoration: none;
padding: 15px;
color: black;
font-weight: bold;
}

.Page1 ul a:hover {
background-color: #D91E18;
color: white;
}



.Page2 {
 height: 100vh;
background-color: #DADFE1;
}

.Page3 {
 height: 100vh; 
background-color: #DADFE1;
}

.Page4 {
 height: 100vh; 
background-color: #DADFE1;
}
```

Comment: Hey man, I fixed the getElementByClassname issue, but it only solved fraction of the problem. When I click the button to scroll down, it infinitely scrolls up and down. So, I think the getElementByClassName is not the only issue. Can you please, reopen the question and help me solve the issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Never mind, I solved the other issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code a little:

```
targetDistance = document.getElementsByClassName(el).offsetTop;
```

becomes:

```
targetDistance = document.getElementsByClassName(el)[0].offsetTop;
```

getElementsByClassName returns an array.

Comment: Okay I did that but now it scrolls a bit but the scrolling rolls up and down infinitely. Any help on that too ? Thanks

Comment: Never mind, I solved the other issue. Thanks